# TypeError: redeclaration of let error in Firebug console if running ES6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I am learning ES6, so bear me please.

Following is the code which is running fine, if I click the *Run* button one time, but on second hit it starts showing `TypeError: redeclaration of let myArr` error.

Let me know about this weird (may be not) behavior.

```
let myArr = [34,45,67,2,67,1,5,90];
let evenArr = [];
let oddArr = [];
myArr.forEach(x => {
    if (x % 2 === 0) {
        evenArr.push(x);
    } else {
        oddArr.push(x);
    }
});

console.log(evenArr);
console.log(oddArr);
```

**Error -**

[image: redelaration of let error]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ES6 [does not allow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let) you to do this (redeclaring a block-scoped variable in the same scope):

```
let foo;
let foo;
```

And since the console keeps state until you reload the page (you are in the context of the page after all), the first time you run it you define `myArr` so you cannot redefine it on the second run.

Comment: Ok, but why if I change the `let` to `var` and hit run still it is displaying the error(though on refresh it goes away)

Comment: `let` defined the variable inside the block. It would be very strange (and most likely not intended) if you were able to hoist it into the function scope by redefining it using `var`.

Comment: I have the same question. I read your answer and did a bit of research on `let` but I'm still having a difficult time understanding it. From what you said, he got the error by defining the variable with `let` and then changing it to `var`. However, in my case I started from the beginning with `var` and yet I'm still getting the same error even though I'm not using 'let`.