# Scoping problems when using let in Firefox Scratchpad

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

The following code produces an error when I run it in Firefox 52 Scratchpad:

```
function scope() {
    let x = 1;
}

let x = 2;

/*
Exception: SyntaxError: redeclaration of let x
@Scratchpad/8:1:1
*/
```

How to explain that? The first `x` should be encapsulated in the function and not interfere with the second declaration.

Running this code as a snippet in Chrome, or inside an HTML page with a `<script>` tag in Firefox doesn't trigger the exception. Also wrapping it in a function, or even a pair of `{}` brackets eliminates the problem.

Could it be a bug in Scratchpad?

Comment: Solution: `{ code }`

Comment: Firefox plans to allow console re-declarations eventually: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/is-this-the-only-way-to-avoid-firefox-console-re-declaration-error/68454/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you only run it one time. The second time you try the same code, the original `let x = 2;` is still alive.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Further, you can find on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete that you cannot delete the variable once declared.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of this question, more or less... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398258/typeerror-redeclaration-of-let-error-in-firebug-console-if-running-es6-code

Comment: Yes, I saw that before posting my question, but I thought it's a different case, caused by `x` first appearing in a function. What I really needed was to invoke _Reload and Run_ instead of just _Run_, to reset the context.